# Automatically growing lists in Python

Tags: python, list

Is there a way to make an automatically growing list in Python? What I mean is to make a list that would grow when an index that does not yet exist is referenced. Basically the behaviour of Ruby arrays.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Umm, you're describing the way lists work. What are you trying that isn't working?

Comment: What I mean is that if the context is out of range, it will raise an error. I want the list to grow to a size where the index is accommodated; in Ruby this will fill all the intermediary spots with Nulls.

Comment: What do you want the contents of the not-yet-existing index to be when it is first referenced (and all the elements before it)? Should it be `None` or some other default value?

Comment: It should be what it is assigned; so a[100]=20 for example. I don't care what the empty spots are assigned, as these are overwritten later.

Comment: OK, and what do you want to happen if someone asks for the value of `a[1000]` if it doesn't exist yet? `IndexError` or should the list grow to this size, too?

Comment: Whats the Ruby's behaviour when you request an unexisting reference from the array? What value does it return?

Comment: It returns Null for the "empty" spots. I don't usually program in Ruby, but I thought this was a nice feature.

Comment: Did you consider using a Hash Table?

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Sure it's possible, you just have to use a subclass of list to do it.

```
class GrowingList(list):
    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        if index >= len(self):
            self.extend([None]*(index + 1 - len(self)))
        list.__setitem__(self, index, value)
```

Usage:

```
>>> grow = GrowingList()
>>> grow[10] = 4
>>> len(grow)
11
>>> grow
[None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, None, 4]
```

Comment: Just note that this is only really useful for dense arrays, if you need a structure for sparse arrays then you are better off with a dictionary based solution.

Comment: add a 'fillvalue' argument in the function...so you can do grow.__setitem__(10, 4, True) for example

Comment: @Ant, `__setitem__` is a special method, it's not often called via it's name, but like in the example `grow[10] = 4`.

Comment: i know, but if i really want that behaviour, i should be able to do that without rewriting the func. and doing def __setitem__(self, index, value, fillvalue=None) won't affect the normal usage ;)

Comment: @Ant, you can use it like that if you like, but I'm not modifying my answer.

Comment: ok, no problem..i think it would be better, but if you dont want to (without explainig why) i don't care at all

Comment: I don't think it is good python to add parameters (even default parameters) to special functions, what if the specification changes and it adds another parameter. I think if you need a fillvalue then you should add it to the `__init__` function, but that wouldn't play well with being inherited from list, you'd need to change the `__new__` method, but I'm just trying to write a simple example.

Comment: If you really want fillvalue, it may be easier to put the class definition in a function taking fillvalue and returning the GrowingList class, but I don't think there's a problem with just using `None`. That is, after all, what the OP wanted.

Comment: If want the list to grow whenever an out-of-bounds element is referenced, you'll also need to redefine the `__getitem__` function. Otherwise, something like `grow = GrowingList(); x = grow[5]` will still produce an error.

Comment: I wouldn't add a parameter to `__setitem__()`, but simply add a `fillvalue` parameter to the constructor `__init__()` of growlist and use that within the `__setitem__()` function to determine the default value.

Comment: Note: performance-wise it is considered good practice for an auto-resizing array to **double in size instead of growing by one element**, whenever you are unsure what maximal length your array might achieve. Increasing your array dynamically requires memory allocation, which is expensive if your array as to be moved in memory.

Comment: Therefore, the proposed solution should not be considered when you are dynamically growing your array/list by a fixed amount of elements at the time.

Comment: Note that this solution does not work with negative indexes.

Answer (score 2):

Lists are dynamic in python. It will automatically grow always (up until you hit sys.maxsize) in your program.

```
  l = list()
  l.append(item)
```

Keep doing that.

Comment: No, I mean that it will grow when an out-of-range index is referenced. For example, a=[1,2,3] will grow when a[100]=101 is called.

Comment: What should the values of `a[3]` to `a[99]` be after this?

Comment: In Ruby, intermediate elements are set to `nil`; in Python, `None` would be the logical choice.

Answer (score -1):

No, but you could use a dictionary (hash table) to achieve the same thing.

Comment: Thanks, but I need it to be ordered.

Comment: Then you might try the [OrderedDict](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.OrderedDict) object. ;-)

Comment: They have keys which would act like indices. Not much difference, but saves memory on sparse arrays. The extended list (alternative) approach would also allocate a bunch of unused objects, and also add run time cost to list traversal.

Comment: I see what you mean. However, the reason I wanted this is for implementing a mathematical algorithm where the values of indeces are significant.