# Easiest image processing on Mac

Tags: macos, image-processing, computer-vision, tracking

I am looking for an easy way to process images as an app on Mac – e.g. tracking moving objects, finding objects/faces etc.

This was inspired by a recent SO post: [How to detect a Christmas Tree?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20772893/how-to-detect-a-christmas-tree)

What is the best language for me to code this in, and how would I do it? I don't have any money to spend on software. I am also a complete beginner to image processing!

Thanks,
Fjpackard.

Comment: There is no way to say definitely which language would be best for you to program something like that. Most likely it'd be best to first find what kind of libraries there are available and then decide the programming language in case you're fluent with several. For an example of one rather powerful library, see http://opencv.org/ .

Comment: Thanks for the link! One language I have been looking at (I probably should have included it in the question) is matlab. Is matlab easy? ;)

Comment: @SamiLaine sorry, forgot to tag you in my previous reply – would you mind answering that? Also, I was wondering – with matlab, are there any good (free) compilers? Also, I checked out opencv.org, installed for use with python but can't really use all the features (I need to use Linux!). Thanks, Fjpackard.

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest to get openCV and connect it to Xcode. Numerous resources can be found on the web or in book stores.
See for example:
[OpenCV MacOS installation](http://georgepavlides.info/opencv-and-macos/)
[OpenCV and iOS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1782163840)
[OpenCV and Xcode](http://opencvexperiments.wordpress.com/2012/11/15/opencvonxcode/)
[OpenCV and Xcode](https://sites.google.com/site/learningopencv1/installing-opencv)

Comment: OK, I'll check it out when I get a chance!

Comment: Indeed, OpenCV in C is really very simple once you get the hang of it. It even handles windows for you! 

The install for Xcode and be a pain though.

Comment: @November you are right about the installation...thats why I had to write a blog entry about this in the first link I provided in my answer...

Answer (score 0):

I think ipython notebook, and one of the the open source python distributions are two tools to look at.  Also, there are some talks from PyData on Vimeo on how to do image processing with python based tool.

One of the python modules you can look at is called scikit-image.

The advantage of the ipython notebook is speakers often post their talks, so if they share their notebooks you can download them and follow along.  I did that with one of the image processing talks from pydata and most of the code and images worked.