# Automatically growing 2D list in python?

Tags: python, list, python-3.x

After reading [Automatically growing lists in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4544630/automatically-growing-lists-in-python), I'm now attempting to create an automatically growing 2 dimensional list.
Basically I would say

```
>>> l = 2DGrowingList(' ') # Fills the inner lists with space (' ') character
>>> l[1][2] = 'x'
>>> print(l)
[[], [' ', ' ', 'x']]
>>> l[0][1] = 'a'
>>> print(l)
[[' ', 'a'], [' ', ' ', 'x']]
```

What I attempted was this:

```
class GrowingList(list):

    def __init__(self, fill):
        super().__init__()
        self.fill = fill

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        if index > len(self) - 1:
            self.extend([self.fill] * (index + 1 - len(self)))
        list.__setitem__(self, index, value)
```

Now I tried to create a new 2D list like so:

```
l = GrowingList(GrowingList(' '))
```

But it doesn't work as intented, since it uses the same instance for filling the lists:

```
>>> l[3][0] = 'x'
>>> print(l)
[[], [], [], ['x']]
>>> l[1][0] = 'y'
>>> print(l)
[['y'], ['y'], ['y'], 'x']
```

Besides, it doesn't allow me to use `l[0][2] = ...` instantly, but I must first call `l[0]` before I can access `l[0][2]`

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary Not really, even if I used list comprehension, the same instance would still be copied...

Comment: Isn't that obvious, you need to create new instances in the list comprehension.

Comment: @Aशwiniचhaudhary How's that possible, the instance isn't always of the same class with sama attributes? And that doesn't fix the issue where I must set `l[0]` before I can access `l[0][0]`

Comment: Just override `__getitem__` too. (and yes, the rest of the thread is a dup of the linked thread)

Comment: On a side note: You could just use a `dict` as a potential sparse container for your rows, and possibly the same for your columns... Then when you need lists, just materialise as many rows/columns as needed with suitable defaults...

Answer (score 0):

It would be possible to solve this by changing your class to use a factory function, rather than a fill value. But if you want to do 2D indexing directly, without ever setting anything in the outer list directly, you'll need to make `__getitem__` extend the list in addition to `__setitem__`. That's because `l[x][y]` tries to get `l[x]` first, before setting the `y`th index within it.

A better approach may be to use a dictionary with keys that are `row, column` tuples. You can use `dict.get` to check for values and get a default for missing keys.

```
l = {}
l[3, 5] = "x"
l[0, 0] = "y"
l[9, 9] = "z"
for i in range(10):
    print("".join(l.get((i, j), ".") for j in range(10))) # "." is default value
```

This prints:

```
y.........
..........
..........
.....x....
..........
..........
..........
..........
..........
.........z
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution for your problem might be using a callable tu build the fill value, in order to have different instances in the matrix.

```
    class GrowingList(list):

    def __init__(self, fill):
        super().__init__()
        self.fill = fill

    def __setitem__(self, index, value):
        if index > len(self) - 1:
            self.extend(self.fill() for i in range(index + 1 - len(self)))
        list.__setitem__(self, index, value)
```

Note that fill is now a callable, so you need to wrap it inside a function:

```
l = GrowingList(lambda: GrowingList(lambda: ' '))
```

You can't rely on the item multiplication idiom either, as it just repeats the value *n* times. To avoid this, a list comprehension is used.

This approach still has a problem, though:

```
l = GrowingList(lambda: GrowingList(lambda: ' '))
l[1][3] = 1

IndexError: list index out of range
```

You may want to consider using a dictionary for a disperse matrix as suggested by Blckknght.