# Efficient growing pools of objects

Tags: python, performance

Is there an established module, or good practice, to work efficiently with large object pools in Python 3?

What I mean by "object pool" is some class capable of:

- fetching new instances of specified type, while dynamically extending the memory allocation under the hood when necessary;
- maintaining a consistent indexing for previously fetched objects.

Here is a basic example:

```
class Value:
    __slots__ = ('a','b')
    def __init__(self,a=None,b=None):
        self.a = a
        self.b = b

class BasicPool:
    def __init__(self):
        self.data = []
    def __getitem__(self,k):
        return self.data[k]
    def fetch(self):
        v = Value()
        self.data.append(v)
        return v

class BlockPool:
    def __init__(self,bsize=100):
        self.bsize = bsize
        self.next = bsize
        self.data = []
    def __getitem__(self,k):
        b,k = divmod(k,self.bsize)
        return self.data[b][k]
    def fetch(self):
        self.next += 1
        if self.next >= self.bsize:
            self.data.append([ Value() for _ in range(self.bsize) ])
            self.next = 0
        return self.data[-1][self.next]
```

The `BasicPool` doesn't do anything smart: whenever a new instance is requested, it is instanciated and appended to an underlying `list`. On the other hand, the `BlockPool` grows a list of pre-allocated blocks of instances. Surprisingly though, it seems that preallocation is **not** beneficial in practice:

```
from timeit import default_timer as timer

def benchmark(P):
    N = int(1e6)
    start = timer()
    for _ in range(N): P.fetch()
    print( timer() - start )

print( 'Basic pool:' )
for _ in range(5): benchmark(BasicPool())

#     Basic pool:
#     1.2352294209995307
#     0.5003506309985823
#     0.48115064000012353
#     0.48508202800076106
#     1.1760561199989752

print( 'Block pool:' )
for _ in range(5): benchmark(BlockPool())

#     Block pool:
#     0.7272855400005938
#     1.4875716509995982
#     0.726611527003115
#     0.7369502859983186
#     1.4867010340021807
```

As you can see, the `BasicPool` is always faster than the `BlockPool` (I also don't know the cause of these large variations). Pools of objects must be a fairly common need in Python; is the best approach really to use the builtin `list.append`? Are there smarter containers that can be used to further improve runtime performance, or is this dominated by the instanciation time anyway?

Comment: In `BlockPool.fetch()` you have `self.data.append( [Value()]*self.bsize )`. This is creating only one instance of `Value`. Change it to `[ Value() for _ in range(bsize) ]`

Comment: @AndrejKesely Thanks a lot for spotting this; this actually makes `BlockPool` less efficient.. I will edit my post.

Comment: `list` itself is a dynamic array which is almost the same as you implement. And it is implemented with C code which makes it much faster. Well, I think it completely fits your requirements?

Comment: @Sraw It would appear so; I am just wondering if there are even more efficient ways or not :)

Comment: You're still adding one at a time, although it is in a block sized loop. In a language that supports direct memory management, growing a pool is typically by a multiplier -- I'm not sure if you gain from a fixed grow size.

Comment: See the linked answer in the comment under the answer here. It grows it by adding instances of None. That should help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole point of the geometric growth of the array underlying a `list` is to reduce the reallocation overhead to a **constant** factor.  That constant can easily be smaller than that for manually making blocks (principally because of the slow, interpreted manipulation of `self.next` and `self.data` in the latter).  (Asymptotically, the cost of `BlockPool.fetch` is *still* the `append`, of course.)  Moreover, your benchmark doesn’t include the additional cost of destroying the blocks, nor that of the two-step indexing on read.

So `list` is surely as good as it gets (without writing your own C code).  You can improve `BasicPool` a bit by **inheriting** from `list` rather than containing one, eliminating a dictionary lookup per `fetch` and the interpreted `__getitem__` wrapper entirely.

Comment: FYI growing pools inheriting from `list` can be implemented as in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4544699/472610).